# VBA - Não consigo referenciar há um Range usando o método Cells - ERRO 400

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Esse primeiro método me da um ERRO 400

```
Worksheets("RELAT").Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i + 1, 12)).Value = Worksheets(mes).Range("P5:Y6").Value
```

Esse segundo método funciona normalmente

```
Worksheets("RELAT").Range("C7:L8").Value = Worksheets(mes).Range("P5:Y6").Value
```

O Primeiro e o segundo método não são as mesmas coisas ? O que tem de errado ?

Código completo:

```
Sub atualizar_Relatorio()
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim mes As String
     
    j = 1
    
    For i = 7 To 30 Step 2
     mes = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value    'pegando o mês na planilha
     
     MsgBox (mes & " " & i)     'testando o nome do mês na msgbox, código roda normalmente até aqui


     Worksheets("RELAT").Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i + 1, 12)).Value = Worksheets(mes).Range("P5:Y6").Value   'este não funciona
     Worksheets("RELAT").Range("C7:L8").Value = Worksheets(mes).Range("P5:Y6").Value      'este funciona

    Next i
    
    
End Sub
```

Resumo do código:
Estou pegando um range (valores) de uma planilha (a qual pego o nome (mês) na planilha `"RELAT"` usando o `for`) e estou copiando os valores desta em outra planilha usando a referência por células, para que eu possa fazer a alteração de linha na planilha `"RELAT"` para que os dados não sejam substituídos, porém o Excel me mostra um Erro 400.

Substitui o `for` pelo seguinte código, porém queria reduzir usando o `for`

Código que estou usando e está funcionando:

```
Sub atualizar_Relatorio()

Worksheets("RELATÓRIO").Activate    

Worksheets("RELAT").Range("C7:L8").Value = Worksheets("JANEIRO").Range("P5:Y6").Value
Worksheets("RELAT").Range("C9:L10").Value = Worksheets("FEVEREIRO").Range("P5:Y6").Value
Worksheets("RELAT").Range("C11:L12").Value = Worksheets("MARÇO").Range("P5:Y6").Value
Worksheets("RELAT").Range("C13:L14").Value = Worksheets("ABRIL").Range("P5:Y6").Value
Worksheets("RELAT").Range("C15:L16").Value = Worksheets("MAIO").Range("P5:Y6").Value
Worksheets("RELAT").Range("C17:L18").Value = Worksheets("JUNHO").Range("P5:Y6").Value
Worksheets("RELAT").Range("C19:L20").Value = Worksheets("JULHO").Range("P5:Y6").Value
Worksheets("RELAT").Range("C21:L22").Value = Worksheets("AGOSTO").Range("P5:Y6").Value
Worksheets("RELAT").Range("C23:L24").Value = Worksheets("SETEMBRO").Range("P5:Y6").Value
Worksheets("RELAT").Range("C25:L26").Value = Worksheets("OUTUBRO").Range("P5:Y6").Value
Worksheets("RELAT").Range("C27:L28").Value = Worksheets("NOVEMBRO").Range("P5:Y6").Value
Worksheets("RELAT").Range("C29:L30").Value = Worksheets("DEZEMBRO").Range("P5:Y6").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Só respondemos perguntas em português no SOPT

Comment: ok, fiz a edição, obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não pode misturar os conceitos de `Range` e `Cells`.

**Range**
Seleciona uma célula ou um intervalo, o argumento é referenciado igualmente ao utilizado em fórmulas nativas, com letra para coluna e número para linha. Exemplos: "A1" ou "A1:B5".

**Cells**
Seleciona uma célula específica, o argumento é referenciado com números. O primeiro referente a linha e o segundo referente a coluna. Exemplo: "(1, 1)"

Portanto, não é possível referenciar um dentro do outro da forma que espera, como um endereçamento.

---

O caso em específico:

Há outras opções, mas eu sugeriria deixar os argumentos da `Range` dinâmicos, mesclando variáveis (para as linhas) e referências diretas (para as colunas), similar a:

```
Worksheets("RELAT").Range("C" & i & ":L" & i + 1).Value = Worksheets(mes).Range("P5:Y6").Value
```

Ao executar o código, supondo que `i = 7`, teremos a construção:

```
Worksheets("RELAT").Range("C7:L8").Value = Worksheets(mes).Range("P5:Y6").Value
```

Comment: compreendi a diferença de Range e Cells, porém quando utilizo a seguinte estrutura que está no código:

Range(Cells (i,j) , Cells(x,y)) eu estaria selecionando um range no intervalo de 2 células não ? eu achei que ja havia usado deste método e outro código, mas devo estar enganado então
Vou testar conforme me indicou e depois comento aqui

Comment: Muito o brigado Jean, deu certo esta sintaxe que me passou, mas ainda estou encabulado que jurava ja ter visto algo do tipo que usei anteriormente kkk

Mas agradecido !